# How can I draw paths in a triangular grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a particular path in a triangular grid using tikz LaTeX like in the picture below. How can I do that?

[image: z]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is it the grid that you have a problem with, or is it the drawing of arrows on a grid? Do you already have a code for the grid?

Answer (score 7):

To build the arrows, I created a new coordinate system in which the x-axis is horizontal and the y-axis is the side of the 60° angle.
It is called `triangular` and its alias is `tri`.

## Update New coordinate system

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\define@key{triangularkeys}{x}{\def\myx{#1}}
\define@key{triangularkeys}{y}{\def\myy{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{triangular}%
{%
\setkeys{triangularkeys}{#1}%
\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointpolarxy{60}{\myx}}{\pgfpointpolarxy{120}{\myy}}
}
\makeatother
\tikzaliascoordinatesystem{tri}{triangular}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm,>=Latex]

% the grid
\foreach \j in {0,...,1} {
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
    \draw[gray](0:\i)++(60:\j)++(120:\j)--++(60:2)--++(-1,0)--++(-60:2);
    
    \draw[gray](0:\i)++(90:{(1+2*\j)*sin(60)})--++(1,0);
}}
\draw(current bounding box.north west)rectangle(current bounding box.south east);


% the arrows
\draw [thick,red,->](tri cs:x=1,y=0)--node[below]{x}++(tri cs:x=1,y=0);
\draw [thick,blue,->](tri cs:x=1,y=0)--node[below]{y}++(tri cs:x=0,y=1);

\draw [thick,violet,->] (1,0)++(tri cs:x=1,y=0)--++(tri cs:x=1,y=0);
\draw [thick,violet,->] (tri cs:x=2,y=0)++(1,0)--++(tri cs:x=0,y=-1);
\draw [thick,violet,->] (2,0)++(tri cs:x=1,y=0)--++(tri cs:x=1,y=0);
\draw [thick,violet,->] (2,0)++(tri cs:x=2,y=0)--++(tri cs:x=0,y=-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\define@key{triangularkeys}{x}{\def\myx{#1}}
\define@key{triangularkeys}{y}{\def\myy{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{triangular}%
{%
\setkeys{triangularkeys}{#1}%
\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointxy{\myx}{0}}{\pgfpointpolarxy{60}{\myy}}
}
\makeatother
\tikzaliascoordinatesystem{tri}{triangular}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75cm, y=0.75cm,>=Latex]

% the grid
\foreach \j in {0,...,1} {
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
    \draw[gray](0:\i)++(60:\j)++(120:\j)--++(60:2)--++(-1,0)--++(-60:2);
    
    \draw[gray](0:\i)++(90:{(1+2*\j)*sin(60)})--++(1,0);
}}
\draw(current bounding box.north west)rectangle(current bounding box.south east);


% the arrows
\draw [thick,blue,->](tri cs:x=0,y=0)--node[below]{x}(tri cs:x=3,y=0);
\draw [thick,blue,->](tri cs:x=0,y=0)--node[left]{y}(tri cs:x=0,y=3);

\draw [thick,violet,->] (tri cs:x=1,y=1)--(tri cs:x=1,y=2);
\draw [thick,violet,->] (tri cs:x=1,y=2)--(tri cs:x=2,y=1);
\draw [thick,violet,->] (tri cs:x=2,y=1)--(tri cs:x=2,y=2);
\draw [thick,violet,->] (tri cs:x=2,y=2)--(tri cs:x=3,y=1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you AndréC

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to achieve what you want by defining the triangles in loops.
It is possible to increase the size of the drawing by just modifying the dimensions and adding steps in the loops.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \draw[thick] (-2.5, -{sqrt(3)/2}) rectangle (2.5, {sqrt(3)});
        
        \path[clip] (-2.5, -{sqrt(3)/2}) rectangle (2.5, {sqrt(3)});
        
        \foreach \x in {-1,0,1}{
            \foreach \y in {-3.5,-2.5,...,2.5}{
                \draw ({\y - 0.5*Mod(\x+1,2)},{\x*sqrt(3)/2}) -- ++ (60:1) -- ++ (-60:1) -- cycle;
            }
        }

        \coordinate (next) at (-2, 0);
    
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}{
            \draw[-Latex,blue] (next) -- ++ (60:1) coordinate (next);
            \draw[-Latex,blue] (next) -- ++ (-60:1) coordinate (next);
        }
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: Thank you KersouMan