# Drawing a square grid and a triangular grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs, wide-image

I was wondering if there is a way of coding regular square and triangular lattices like these ones in the images on latex. I know how to generate regular polygons (square, triangle, hexagon etc), but I would like to know if there is a way to create these lattices as well.

[image][image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Square grids are native to TikZ with ``draw [step=.5](0,0)grid(2,1.5);``for example. See the `14.8 The Grid Operation` in the pgfmanual.

Comment: To create triangular grids you can adapt the answers to this question: [How can I draw isometric dot paper with a scale size of 1cm with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559633/138900)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (-0.2,-0.2) grid (4.2,3.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \clip (-0.2,-0.2) coordinate (bl) rectangle (4.2,3.2) coordinate (tr);
 \draw[xslant={1/sqrt(2)},yscale={1/sqrt(2)}] (-2,-0.2) grid (6,4.2);
 \draw[xslant=-{1/sqrt(2)},yscale={1/sqrt(2)}] (-2,-0.2) grid (6,4.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How would I add the points on the intersections of these graphs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a regular triangular grid with dots, you may try this (based on [a solution by AndréC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556909/204164)).
[image: triangular grid with dots]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{d/.style={minimum width=2pt,inner sep=0pt,circle,fill=black}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \def\nx{5}
        \def\ny{3} \pgfmathsetmacro\nyy{(2+2*\ny)*sin(60)}
        
        \draw[cyan] (0,0) rectangle (\nx +1,\nyy);
        \foreach \j in {0,...,\ny} {
            \foreach \i in {0,...,\nx} {
                \draw[cyan](0:\i)++(90:{(1+2*\j)*sin(60)})--++(1,0);
                \draw[cyan](0:\i) ++(60:\j) ++(120:\j) node[d] {} --++(60:2) node[d] {} --++(-1,0) node[d] {} --++(-60:1) node[d] {} --++(-60:1) node[d] {};
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And if you want to add dots on your square grid, just nest two `\foreach` loops, like this:

[image: square grid with dots]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\nx{6} \def\ny{4}
        \draw [cyan] (0,0) grid (\nx,\ny);
        \foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
            \foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}
                \node[d] at (\i,\j) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```